# Should static variables ever be used as method parameters?

Tags: apex

Should you design a method where it's params are static variables? In the example below, the calc method is pretty reusable, but it seems wierd to pass in static variables....

Setup

In class A, i have a static variable num and a static method genBalance. In my utility class B, i have a static method that does some calculations and uses the varialbe. Id does not modify it.

```
public class A{
    public static Integer num;

    static{
    num = 0;
    } 

    public static String genBalance(){
        return 'You have a balance of : ' + B.calc(num);
    }

}

public Class B{
    public static Integer calc(integer a){
        return a*10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should this line be "return 'You have a balance of : ' + B.calc(num);"
instead of "return 'You have a balance of : ' + calc(num);"

Comment: thx, fixed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can. Usually, this is because the method being called is in a utility class, where the method itself is used in a number of places, and the static member is a constant (static final). It's certainly unusual, and I'd argue that it's rarely the best design, especially given the CPU cost of static final members, but there's nothing wrong with it if you need to.

Comment: Could you help me with a better design?

Comment: @user11235813 It really depends on the use case. It might be a local variable, a class variable, a custom label, or something else. I don't think that there's a "one size fits all" solution.

Answer (score 0):

This link explains the use of static variable/methods compared to other types of variables/methods. Hope this explains why they have to be used. I have used this as a reference in my coding.
 https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm